# Can a deployed Flask web service make SageMaker inference calls?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

While running locally the following code works, it is erroring in my deployed Flask app. The error is:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: User: arn:aws:sts::12345678910:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-12f12f824f348ce81 is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:InvokeEndpoint on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-west-2:12345678910:endpoint/example_endpoint-2021-10-20-19-02-21 because no identity-based policy allows the sagemaker:InvokeEndpoint action
```

Curious if it is at all possible for the Flask Service to call the SageMaker? Or is it that I just did not set my permissions correctly? If it is possible for the Flask Service to be able to call InvokeEndpoint, then how should I set the elastic beanstalk instance/environment to have the correct permission to access the SageMaker's invokeEndpoint API?

```
import time
from flask import Flask, request
from ow.t2i_translator import T2ITranslatorController
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_session import Session
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
import logging
import json
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import requests, os, json
import boto3

application = app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
Session(app)
api = Api(app)
class ABCController:
  ENDPOINT_NAME="example_endpoint-2021-10-20-19-02-21"
  def __init__(self):
    self.client = boto3.client("runtime.sagemaker", region_name="us-west-2")

  def getCall(self, data)
    return self.client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName=self.ENDPOINT_NAME,
        ContentType='application/json',
        Body=json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
    )

# NOTE: This route is needed for the default EB health check route
@app.route('/')  
def home():
  return "Hello!"

@app.route('/call', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def get_call():
  c = ABCController()
  return c.getCall(request.data)
```

Comment: have you found a solution?